# Formatting microSD card for half capacity

Tags: micro-sd-card

Some devices have limitations for microSD card size (e.g. 8GB or 16GB). Is it possible to format a 16GB microSD card so that it appears to have 8GB on the device?

Answer (score 1):

Yes and no, it depends on how the device is limited.

If the device has a hardware limitation that limits it to a certain size you can't work around this by formatting as that doesn't change the physical characteristics of the card.

If the device has a software-limit that limits the maximum file-system size you simple create a partition (with your partitioning tool of choice) just a little bit smaller than the maximum size and format that with the filesystem required by the device.
Having the device itself doing the formatting typically won't work as it will try to use the whole card in that case, which is too big.